# Realizar una función al llegar a una sección de la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Tengo un programa que tiene una sección de estadísticas. Al completar la carga de la página, se empiezan a aumentar las estadísticas.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 aumentarTec();
 aumentarMercado();
 aumentarUsuarios();
});

function aumentarTec(){
   <?php
   $consultar_tec=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_proyecto FROM proyectos");
   $ct=$consultar_tec->num_rows;
   ?>
   var limite_t=6;
   $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var l = 0; l <= limite_t; l++) {
     (function (l) {
      setTimeout(function () {
       $("#tec_valoradas").html(l);
      }, 50*l);
     })(l);
    }
   });
  }

  function aumentarMercado(){
   <?php
   $consultar_trl=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_proyecto FROM proyectos WHERE trl_proyecto='TRL 7' OR trl_proyecto='TRL 8' OR trl_proyecto='TRL 9'");
   $ctrl=$consultar_trl->num_rows;
   ?>
   var limite_trl=10;
   $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var j = 0; j <= limite_trl; j++) {
     (function (j) {
      setTimeout(function () {
       $("#trl_mercado").html(j);
      }, 50*j);
     })(j);
    }
   });
  }

  function aumentarUsuarios(){
   <?php
   $consultar_usu=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT documento_usuario FROM usuarios");
   $cusu=$consultar_usu->num_rows;
   ?>
   var limite_usu=6;
   $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var k = 0; k <= limite_usu; k++) {
     (function (k) {
      setTimeout(function () {
       $("#usuarios_registrados").html(k);
      }, 50*k);
     })(k);
    }
   });
  }
```

```html
<section id="observar_estadisticas">
   <section id="datos_estadisticos">
    <table id="estadsticos_tabla">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th id="tec_valoradas">0</th>
       <th id="posibles_patentes">0</th>
       <th id="trl_mercado">0</th>
       <th id="usuarios_registrados">0</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>TECNOLOG&Iacute;AS VALORADAS</td>
       <td>POSIBLES PATENTES</td>
       <td>TECNOLOG&Iacute;AS EN EL MERCADO</td>
       <td>USUARIOS</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </section>
   <img src="./imagenes/estadisticas.png" id="estadisticas">
  </section>
```

Este es el procedimiento. Quisiera que no es activara con el método .ready(), si no que al llegar a esa sección con id "observar estadísticas", se activen todos los eventos. Lo intenté con scroll(), pero no me activa nada.

Lo intento con `$(document).scroll("#observar_estadisticas");`, pero al simplemente hacer scroll en cualquier lugar de la página se activa. Y si intento con `$("#observar_estadisticas").scroll(function(e));` no me activa nada. Lo he probado con alert, pero ni siquiera entra al evento. Por favor, si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas Bootstrap puedes hacerlo con **[Scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/)**

---

Si no usas bootstrap puede hacerlo con **JQuery/JS**:

La idea es bastante simple, quedarte con cuanta distancia tiene tu elemento hasta el top.

```
var elementoScrollTop= $("#estadisticas").offset().top; // jQuery
var elementoScrollTop= document.getElementById("estadisticas").offsetTop; // JS
```

Y en el evento de Scoll:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){...}); // jQuery
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){...}); // JS
```

Obtienes cuanta distancia hay actualmente hasta el top, y si es `>=` a la del elemento ejecutas tu función:

```
function(){
    // jQuery
    var actualScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(actualScrollTop >= elementoScrollTop){
        tuFuncion()
    }
    // JS
    var actualScrollTop = window.scrollY;
    if(actualScrollTop >= elementoScrollTop){
        tuFuncion()
    }
}
```

**Snippet jQuery:**

```js
var executedOnScroll = false;
var elementoScrollTop = $("#estadisticas").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
  var actualScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("#infoScroll").html(Math.round(actualScrollTop)+"/"+Math.round(elementoScrollTop));
  if(actualScrollTop >= elementoScrollTop && executedOnScroll == false){
    //Tu funcion a ejecutar
    executedOnScroll = true;
    console.log("SE EJECUTA");
    $("#estadisticas").html("Cargando estadisticas...");
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: auto;
}

.containerDiv {
  height: 400px;
}

#div1{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div2{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#estadisticas{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div4{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#infoScroll {
  position: fixed;
  top 0;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="infoScroll"></span>
<div id="div1" class="containerDiv">

</div>
<div id="div2" class="containerDiv">

</div>
<div id="estadisticas" class="containerDiv">

</div>
<div id="div4" class="containerDiv">

</div>
```

**Snippet JS:**

```js
var executedOnScroll = false;
var elementoScrollTop = document.getElementById("estadisticas").offsetTop;
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  var actualScrollTop = window.scrollY;
  document.getElementById("infoScroll").textContent=Math.round(actualScrollTop)+"/"+Math.round(elementoScrollTop);
  if(actualScrollTop >= elementoScrollTop && executedOnScroll == false){
    //Tu funcion a ejecutar
    executedOnScroll = true;
    console.log("SE EJECUTA");
    document.getElementById("estadisticas").textContent="Cargando estadisticas...";
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: auto;
}

.containerDiv {
  height: 400px;
}

#div1{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div2{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#estadisticas{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div4{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#infoScroll {
  position: fixed;
  top 0;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <span id="infoScroll"></span>
  <div id="div1" class="containerDiv">

  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="containerDiv">

  </div>
  <div id="estadisticas" class="containerDiv">

  </div>
  <div id="div4" class="containerDiv">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oye, muchísimas gracias. Y también gracias por la explicación. ¿Esto serviría para otros id?

Comment: si claro, donde pone `estadisticas` tienes que poner tu id. Y si quieres puedes tener varios ifs comprobando varios elementos y en cada uno ejecutar una función diferente.