# Activar animación al llegar a cierto punto de la pagina

Tags: html, css

Estoy buscando la manera de que un elemento realicé una animación cuando el usuario llegue a visualizarla en la pagina

Código:

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    /* url(img/fondo.jpg); */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    position: relative;
  }
  
.header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(97, 166, 14, .7), rgb(0, 73, 135, .7));
}

.imagen-box {
    padding: 10px;
}
.header .logo-box img {
    height: 5vh;
}

.imagen-data .img-main-data,
.imagen-data .img-data{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.imagen-data .img-main-data {
    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.data-planning {
    text-align: center;
}

.data-planning h1{
    font-weight: 300;
}
.data-planning .titulo-data {
    color: #004987;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.data-planning .btn {
    background: #004987;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
}

.modal-footer .btn-salir {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #004987;
}

.modal-footer .btn-entrar {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #56A419;
}

.modal-title {
    color: #0D0106;
}

.modal-body label{
    color: #0D0106;
}


.texto {
    text-align: center;
    color: #1A1D21;
    font-weight: 400;
}


/*ANIMACIONES*/
@keyframes moveInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Data Planning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- logo bancamiga -->
            <div class="row pt-4 pb-4">
                <div class="logo-box col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img src="img/1x/Recurso 1.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- caja de la bienvenida y la imagen -->
            <div class="row imagen-box d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 data-planning">
                    <h1>Bienvenidos a <span class="titulo-data">Data Planning</span></h1>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, totam?.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ingreso">Comencemos</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="ingreso" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Iniciar Sesión</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Exam: BA0000">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Exam: 123456">
                                </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-salir" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar">Entrar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 imagen-data">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="data" class="img-main-data">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-4 mt-4">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center imagen-data">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" class="img-data">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Explicabo commodi accusamus doloremque animi optio, culpa illo? 
                        Atque magni odit magnam sequi? Perferendis commodi 
                        optio autem obcaecati quae rem pariatur dolorem maiores, 
                        quos placeat quo, odio aliquid? Dolore ut sapiente impedit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-4 mt-4">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Explicabo commodi accusamus doloremque animi optio, culpa illo? 
                        Atque magni odit magnam sequi? Perferendis commodi 
                        optio autem obcaecati quae rem pariatur dolorem maiores, 
                        quos placeat quo, odio aliquid? Dolore ut sapiente impedit.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 imagen-data d-flex align-items-center">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" class="img-data">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-4 mt-4">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center imagen-data">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" class="img-data">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Explicabo commodi accusamus doloremque animi optio, culpa illo? 
                        Atque magni odit magnam sequi? Perferendis commodi 
                        optio autem obcaecati quae rem pariatur dolorem maiores, 
                        quos placeat quo, odio aliquid? Dolore ut sapiente impedit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

La idea es que cuando el usuario visualice la segunda parte de la página (que son las 3 imagenes) poder hacer una animación a dichas imagenes.

Comment: Creo que te puede servir esta pregunta [Realizar una función al llegar a una sección de la página](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280803/realizar-una-funci%c3%b3n-al-llegar-a-una-secci%c3%b3n-de-la-p%c3%a1gina)